# How to add legend mixture of text and value in matplotlib python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted the bar graph and want to add custom legend (average value)

I have specified average value in the code and I want to present the average value with the text.
below annotate code seems doesn't work so is there any other way to present text and the value together?

```
ax.annotate("Average-"+AVG+"bar", xy=(0,0.8), xycoords='axes fraction', color='red',fontsize=18)
```

Here is code I've got so far.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=12,9))

x = np.arange(8)

label = ['#1','#2','#3','#4','#5']
values = [107.1,106.2,104,102.8,106.1]
AVG =(df['values'].to_numpy()).astype(float)

ax.axhspan(AVG-7, AVG+7, facecolor='#e9e9c6', alpha=0.5)

ax.bar(label, values, width=0.35)
ax.axhline(AVG, color='red', linewidth=0.8)

ax.annotate("Average-"+AVG+"bar", xy=(0,0.8), xycoords='axes fraction', color='red',fontsize=18)

fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: You can find the answer to any matplotlib question in the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html).

Comment: I can find the document where I type the actual number but can't find how to use annotate with list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to annotate the average value as a custom legend outside the plot, this code will work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))

label = ['#1','#2','#3','#4','#5']
values = [107.1,106.2,104,102.8,106.1]
# AVG =(df['values'].to_numpy()).astype(float)
AVG = np.mean(values)

ax.axhspan(AVG-7, AVG+7, facecolor='#e9e9c6', alpha=0.5)

ax.bar(label, values, width=0.35)
ax.axhline(AVG, color='red', linewidth=0.8)

# You need to define ylim in order to calculate xy position for annotation
ax.set_ylim(0, max(values) + 10)

ax.annotate(f"Average-{AVG:.4f} bar", xy=(1.01, AVG / (max(values) + 10) - .01), xycoords='axes fraction', color='red',fontsize=18)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: Click here to check the output]